# Unable to use CXImage library

Tags: c++, c, image, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008

I am new to Microsoft Visual Studio  and i want to use third party CXImage library as a part of my C++ program. After long search i found Japanese site [here](http://micropilot.tistory.com/entry/CxImage-with-VC-2012) read it through chrome translator but still not clear how to achieve this.Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It is look quite simple task. just need to open the sln file. Where is your problem? to open the project file with your vs? to change the project setting? or maybe some compilation error?